# jQuery ui multi select shows comma-separated texts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a jQuery.UI multiselect by Eric Hynds [this is the link](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

I want to show the multiple selected texts comma-separated.

Any ideas?

Comment: where do you want to show the comma separated valued?

Comment: @SadikhasanI have a question in general. I want to know if it is possible?

Comment: @Arun P Johny in the dropdown text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selectedText` option

```
$('selector').multiselect({
    selectedText: function (sCount, tCount, els) {
        if (sCount) {
            return $.map(els, function (el) {
                return $(el).val()
            }).join()
        } else {
            'None'
        }
    }
})
```